# How to ask friends for help?

Tags: networking, mentoring, social-skills

I have some contacts on a social networking site who are much more knowledgeable than me. Some are PhDs/professors and some work in big tech companies (Google, Facebook, etc.). Every now and then, I would have some questions to ask, and often times I cannot get the (timely) answers from Q and A sites like StackExchange or Quora.

Every time I attempt to turn to them for help, I would hesitate because they have not replied to my last message. In such messages, I just describe my questions and ask if they would give me some suggestions or directions.

I wonder how to network to find more support from "friends"? I don't know how others socialize for help, and others don't ask me for help with specific technique questions. Often others ask me for recommendations like books or courses and I would try my best to help.

How do you deal with specific questions when you feel that it's time to find someone to discuss or ask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often the people you are approaching for help as you describe, have plenty of deadlines to keep up with and along with maintaining personal life and other chores, there is no room for tending to questions like yours, that too over social media. This is not because they are unfriendly towards you, but it's just life.
You can of course still get help from them and have a discussion in your favour by helping them with structuring your questions. So:

1. Ask questions focussed on the specifics - like what, when, where and so on - on the said topic. Like if you are asking for which course to take to learn about machine learning, list a few options that are available to you. This shows that you have done some research and are truly interested in learning a new skill.
2. Different people have different preferred modes of communication. For me it is email. You can ask what their preferences are.
3. Often, a quick call is better than long walls of text, in which case, you should take notes while on call to stick to the details of the discussion.
4. Leave a "thank you" message for them later, this shows that they contributed to your career/personality growth.
5. I find it weird when completely unknown people ask for help on a career. So build on your networks for a while, instead of dropping random questions in the chatbox. Nobody (and in future, you) appreciates that.
6. Remember that it is you getting help from them, they don't gain anything from such a discussion, so make it enjoyable for them too - by being polite and humane.

Hope these help.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes, we should be just humans and help each other if we have the heart to.

one could find time

one could stop and listen

one could just get his head out of this glittering reality and be aware of others.

but if one loves himself that much, then he will allmost never find time for others.