# Ways of approaching for internship in industry by a PhD student

Tags: phd, industry, internship

I am a first-year PhD student in Quality Reliability and Operations Research unit at ISI, Kolkata. What are the opportunities for getting an internship in the industry? And how should we plan and approach to get such an internship?

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. Your query seems too broad (with respect to topic). Can you specify on what topic are you interested in getting an internship? You can try to formulate the question in this structure described here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/175691/67456

Comment: To get started ask an advisor or friendly instructor about whom to explore summer internship opportunities with. There'll likely be someone maybe even an office to work with. Employers often advertise summer internships early, at the beginning of the year say, because they want to attract the best and brightest, and will contact departments and offices within the university, present at on-campus job fairs, etc. In turn you need to get in early because, depending on the field I guess, competition can be fierce. But a first step is your advisor. Best of luck!

Comment: @Wandering_Alice I want to get an internship in the Analytics section where I can use probabilistic and statistical methods as well as computing also.

Comment: Thank you @Aruralreader for your explanation.